# Laravel define belongsToMany relation ships without providing second parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In `laravel` i try to make a simple `relation-ship` between two table as `users` and `wallets` without providing second parameter, but when i try to access between them i get error:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sample.user_wallets' doesn't exist

```php
//user
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
    //...

    $table->softDeletes();

    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});

//wallets
Schema::create('wallets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('wallet_name');
    $table->string('wallet_number');
    $table->timestamps();
});

//user_wallet
Schema::create('user_wallet', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('wallet_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->primary(['user_id','wallet_id']);
});
```

User model:

```php
public function wallet(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserWallet::class);
}
```

Wallet model:

```php
public function user(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

and by this below code i try to access user's wallets:

```
$this->user_wallets = auth()->user()->with('wallet')->get();
```

Comment: in your wallet function, shouldn't it only be the Wallet class and not the pivot class?

Comment: @Aless55 i think i should be have `pivot`

Comment: If you want to get all wallets for an user there has to be the Wallet::class otherwise I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @Aless55 i have this model class and i pasted relation which i used into that `public function user(): BelongsToMany{return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN Your User Model:
change

```
public function wallet(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserWallet::class);
}
```

To : THis

```
   public function wallets(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class,'user_wallet');
}
```

In Your Wallet Model:

```
  public function users(): BelongsToMany ///not user
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

*Note: U dont need UserWallet Model Since it is belongsTOMany Relationship*
**Suggestion: In real life example a user have many wallet and a wallet is only belongs to one user so the relation is HasMany(on to Many)**

Answer (score 2):

It should be plural. `wallets` and `users`

User Model:

```
public function wallets(): BelongsToMany  //not wallet
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class);
}
```

Wallet model:

```
public function users(): BelongsToMany //not user
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Comment: its shoudnt be pivot table clas it shoud be Wallet ::class

Comment: Sorry, yes it should be Wallet class.